# serving a blog at domain.com/blog when dns for domain.com is pointing elsewhere

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

there is a blog hosted on one machine (apache) (currently at blog.domain.com) and we'd like to move it to domain.com/blog. dns for domain.com is pointed at an haproxy machine load balancing a few nginx app servers. the machine hosting the blog is not behind that load balancer.

considering i have complete control over the configuration of everything, whats the most straightforward way to get this to submit to my will and have the blog served from domain.com/blog?

Comment: You can not achieve this without sending the traffic to your load balancer because the domain is pointing to your load balancer. If you send the traffic to your nginx load balancer then you can easly rewrite the /blog url.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible ways to achieve this. The best one would be to setup a reverse proxy on HAProxy and use acl to divert /blog traffic to the backend blog server.

http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7

Perhaps, have a look at this example setup
http://steven.4bits.eu/2010/07/using-haproxy-as-reverse-proxy.html

You may not need to change the ports as you already mentioned that the blog is hosted on a separate server.